# resample per week on monday

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

i want to sum two columns independently aggregated weekly(on Monday) sum by id and date. .

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x2', 'x2', 'x1', 'x1', 'x1'],
            'date':['2021-01-03','2021-01-09', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01'],
       'distance_europe':[100, 100, 200, 200, 100],
                'distance_USA': [0, 200, 100, 100, 3]})
```

**expected output**

```
2020-12-28  x2  100   0
2020-12-28  x1 500   203
2021-01-04  x2  100  200
```

update  ----
**My solution below works finely** ---------

```
df = df.groupby('id').resample('W', on='date').sum().reset_index()
df['due_date'] = df.date - pd.Timedelta('6D')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with `closed='left'` and `label='left'` with `id` and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x2', 'x2', 'x1', 'x1', 'x1'],
            'date':['2021-01-03','2021-01-09', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01'],
       'distance_europe':[100, 100, 200, 200, 100],
                'distance_USA': [0, 200, 100, 100, 3]})


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-Mon', closed='left', label='left'), 'id'])
       .sum()
       .reset_index())
print (df)
        date  id  distance_europe  distance_USA
0 2020-12-28  x1              500           203
1 2020-12-28  x2              100             0
2 2021-01-04  x2              100           200
```

Your solution is change for grouping from by `Sundays` `(for W is default Sundays)` to `Mondays` with same parameters like above:

```
df = df.groupby('id').resample('W-Mon', on='date', closed='left', label='left').sum().reset_index()

print (df)
   id       date  distance_europe  distance_USA
0  x1 2020-12-28              500           203
1  x2 2020-12-28              100             0
2  x2 2021-01-04              100           200
```

Comment: Thank you ! but i think we haven't same date. My week is based on monday. thank you